# Try to do a unit test in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to understand how unit tests work

I've got this method:

```
public async parseTest(diffComponents: any[]): Promise<Map<string, string[]>> {
    const result: Map<string, string[]> = new Map();
    for (let i = 0; i < diff.length; i++) {
        const element = diff[i];
        try {
            const fileContent = fs.readFileSync("changelog.txt","UTF-8");
            const lines = fileContent.split("\n");
            const list = this.retrieve(lines, element);
            result.set(element.components, list);
        } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject("ERROR: Cannot find file from components");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The ouput of result is for example:

```
Map { 'toto' => [ 'toto-11' ] }
```

And here this is my test but it doesn't work:

```
describe("parse", () => {
    test("check map result", () => {
        // Given
        const array = [{ components: "toto", newVersion: "2.2", oldVersion: "2.1" }];

        // When
        const result = new ChangelogService().parseTest(array);
        const expected = new Map();
        expected.set("toto", "toto-11");
        // Then
        expect(result).toBe(expected);   // problem in this line 
    });
});
```

the error of the line is :

```
Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
Expected: Map {"toto" => "toto-11"}
Received: {}Jest
```

Can you explain the problem or give a better test method?

Comment: What "problem"? What's the output? One obvious issue is you have an async function you aren't awaiting (although it doesn't contain any awaits, so it's unclear why it is async).

Comment: Yes sorry I forget to remove async

Comment: Other problems include using [toBe](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tobevalue) to compare what would be two *separate* Map objects, and the fact that your function doesn't seem to refer to its own parameter.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So what I need to use if using ToBe is not good ?

Comment: I think Maps would compare correctly with toEqual. See e.g. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/using-matchers.html

Answer (score 0):

`.toBe` does exact match, it means it has to be the same object.

if you want compare that objects contain the same key and values you need to use `.toEqual`.

Also you Map is an array, you should do the same in the `expected`.

And the method returns promise you need to solve.

```js
describe("parse", () => {
    test("check map result", async () => { // <- add async
        // Given
        const array = [{ components: "toto", newVersion: "2.2", oldVersion: "2.1" }];

        // When
        const result = await (new ChangelogService().parseTest(array)); // <- add await
        const expected = new Map();
        expected.set("toto", ["toto-11"]); // <- wrap the value
        // Then
        expect(result).toEqual(expected); // <- change to toEqual
    });
});
```

Then jasmine will go through the `result` and check it key by key with `expected`.